# Translate Silverstripe login form and other built in pages

Tags: php, silverstripe

I'm using the [Silverstripe Translatable Plugin](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-translatable) to provide a website in multiple languages. However I'd also like to translate the built in pages like the Login or the Password Reset page. Just applying `?local=en_US` at the end of the URL doesn't seem to help and there is also no way to create a deidcated login page in a second language. Is there any way to get that working?

Comment: I guess you have to check that parameter in Controller::init() yourself and set the Locale manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution. It works by extending the Controller class, which is low enough to also have effect on controllers such as Security, which handles login.

It remembers the locale of the previous page, and then uses that to render the "built-in page".

**ControllerDecorator.php**

```php
<?php
class ControllerDecorator extends Extension {
    function onBeforeInit() {
        // If we're on a page, use its Locale information
        if($this->getOwner() instanceof ContentController) {
            $locale = $this->getOwner()->Locale;
            i18n::set_locale($locale);
            Cookie::set('Locale', $locale);
        }
        // Otherwise, use the stored Locale
        else if(Cookie::get('Locale')) {
            i18n::set_locale(Cookie::get('Locale'));
        }
    }
}
```

**config.yml**

```
Controller:
  extensions:
    - ControllerDecorator
```